# Is scoping a legitimate way to access virtual functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, scoping

I have a C++ program with 4 classes : Person, Student, Employee, and PartTimeStudent.

Student and Employee each derive from Person, and PartTimeStudent derives from all 3 classes (making it the most derived class). All classes have a virtual function called VDescribe().

Please see the code below :

```
class Person
{
    ...    
    virtual void VDescribe();
    ...
};

class Student : virtual public Person
{
    ...    
    virtual void VDescribe();
    ...
};

class Employee : virtual public Person
{
    ...    
    virtual void VDescribe();
    ...
};

class PartTimeStudent : virtual public Person,
    virtual public Student,
    virtual public Employee
{
    ...    
    virtual void VDescribe();
    ...
};
```

Note : In the code snippet above I have omitted the Constructors, Destructors and member variables because they are not relevant to the question.

In addition, I have the following code in which a PartTimeStudent object is created and accessed via a pointer. I use scoping to invoke the VDescribe() functions of the different sub-objects within the PartTimeStudent object.

```
void DoTest()
{
    PartTimeStudent* pPTS = new PartTimeStudent("John", 23, "NTU", "Seven-Eleven");

    pPTS->VDescribe();
    pPTS->::Person::VDescribe();
    pPTS->::Student::VDescribe();
    pPTS->::Employee::VDescribe();
}
```

The code compiles successfully and I am able to invoke the different versions of VDescribe(). What I want to know is, is this a legitimate means of accessing virtual functions? Is this acceptable or a discouraged practice?

Comment: Any reason why `PartTimeStudent::vDescribe()` doesn't call `Person::VDescribe()` and `Student::VDescribe` itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly legal way of bypassing dynamic dispatch and calling a particular version of a virtual function, not its final overrider.

However, I would generally find it strange to see such code on the *outside* of the class, and I'd be checking to see if there's perhaps a design problem or misunderstanding. Normally, such code is used *inside* the class itself to call the overridden version of a function (typically from the overrider).

Comment: Am I right that this is only possible because he used public inheritance? With private inheritance (the default), the fact that `PartTimeStudent` is derived from `Student`, etc. is hidden to outside users.

Comment: @Barmar Yes; to be exact, the calling code must have access to the function with the qualified name.

Comment: isn't it intrinsically dangerous ? (unless the class explicitly allows so) assuming public inheritance is used to model an is-a relationship, bypassing virtual dispatch from the outside could generally break subclass invariants, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a legitimate way to **non-virtually** call these functions. There is no general prohibition, but you have to be careful when doing this in constructors (as your base classes are `virtual`). You must know for certain that the named base sub-object already exists. For non-virtual base classes, this is not an issue as they are constructed in order.